# Generated input and default values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using some generated `input` elements in my App's form, and I'm trying to keep it simple as possible, that's why I'm sticking with native form reset for them.

It seems that the 'default value' is bonded to the element upon the node creation. For example:

```
var inputOne = $('<input value="Original value">');
var inputTwo = $('<input>').val('Original value');
myForm.append([inputOne, inputTwo]);
```

In this example ([here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yAE7h/)) only input one will reset properly, however I need to use something more like was done in input two because I have different kinds on input templates that are much more complex than those in the example given, so a simple string concatenation with the value is not a much viable option.

I've considered to use placeholders in my input templates, like:

```
var myInputTemplate = '<input value="%val" data-foo="%foo" data-bar="%bar">';

var newInputNode = createNodeFromTemplate(myInputTemplate , {
  val: "Original Value",
  foo:"My Foo",
  bar:"My Bar",
});
```

But that's a last resort, remember I'm trying to keep it simple as possible.

---

**The question:**

I read once in the spec that the default value is defined differently for each element type, but no further explanation was given.

How default values are defined for inputs?!

There's some workaround to "redefine" the default value in generated inputs?!

Comment: Did you try $('<input>').attr('value', 'def value')?

Comment: @arty Yes, see the fiddle...

Comment: `$('<input />', {value: 'Original value'})` pass an object

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/yAE7h/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yAE7h/3/

Comment: And the proper jQuery way to set the actual default value would be -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/yAE7h/5/

Comment: @adeneo Could you please produce a answer from your comments so I can accept it?

Comment: @cvsguimaraes i saw the fiddle, did you see my comment? )...

Comment: @arty Meh, now I did! Haha, sorry...

Comment: It's ok, i think you got much better answers anyway, i was just trying to help with a working code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default value at any time with

```
inputTwo.prop('defaultValue','some other value');
```

but that does not update the actual value property, only the default value used when the form is reset, the preferred method for setting the value property is still `val()` as it sets the native `element.value` property

```
inputTwo.val('value');
```

and in most cases you want to change the property, not the attribute, as that can cause a multitude of other issues later.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/yAE7h/6/)

You can also create elements by passing an object

```
var params = {
    value   : 'Original value',
    id      : 'myID',
    'class' : 'myClass' // note the quotes, class is a reserved word in JS
}

$('<input />', params);
```

Comment: Thanks! From my testing, setting `defaultValue` **before** appending the element is enough :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between `$('input').val(something)` and `$('input').attr('value', something)`. The former sets the current value of input. The latter changes the input's `value` attribute, which contains the initial value of the control. That, it turn, allows to correctly process it by `form.reset` - as seen in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mfaya/).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.val()` doesn't change the `value` attribute of the input, simply its content.  Using `.attr()` instead to change the value attribute give the functionality you want.

```
$('<input>').attr('value', 'Original value');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yAE7h/2/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confusing `value` property with `value` attribute.

Input elements have a `value` attribute, which is the value which appears by default and to which is reset. It corresponds to the `defaultValue` propery.

They also have a `value` property which contains the current value, and can be used to set a new one.

In jQuery, `.val()` referes to the property `value`, not the attribute.

Then, if you want to get/set the **default value**, use

```
       |            Get              |                 Set
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JS     | input.getAttribute('value') | input.setAttribute('value', newVal)
jQuery | $input.attr('value')        | $input.attr('value', newVal)

JS     | input.defaultValue          | input.defaultValue = newVal
jQuery | $input.prop('defaultValue') | $input.prop('defaultValue', newVal)
```

Otherwise, if you want to get/set the **current value**, use

```
       |            Get              |                 Set
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JS     | input.value                 | input.value = newVal
jQuery | $input.prop('value')        | $input.prop('value', newVal)
jQuery | $input.val()                | $input.val(newVal)
```